# How to find out if a WFS instance supports filtering via CQL?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, filter, cql-filter, getcapabilities

I am considering using *Common Query Language (CQL)* to add filter parameter to a HTTP *curl* query which runs against a *WFS* server. I found out that [*GeoServer* supports *CQL* via *WFS*](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html).

1. Can I tell from a *GetCapabilities* document if the *WFS* is served by *GeoServer*?
2. How can I test if *CQL* is supported by the *WFS*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is anything that for sure reveals that WFS server is GeoServer but with standard settings the schema location refers somehow to geoserver and some supported functions are special for GeoServer. However, others can implement functions using same names:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities

<wfs:WFS_Capabilities version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" updateSequence="96">

<ogc:FunctionName nArgs="-6">BarnesSurface</ogc:FunctionName>
```

For testing is CQL_FILTER is supported you can try the "IN" filter as in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html

The following request will return one feature from GeoServer and probably all features from other servers (or an error). You must edit "states.1" to suit with the name of the featuretype:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&CQL_FILTER=IN ('states.1')
```

Comment: Thank you. I received the same file as if I omit the `CQL_FILTER` parameters. I also urlencoded the last part of the URL. So, the WFS server seems to not support CQL.