# How to request paginated or filtered data from WFS 2.0?

Tags: wfs, filter, gml, cql-filter, curl

I want to download a data set from a WFS 2.0 server via HTTP GET, with *curl* for instance.

```
$ curl -X GET http://example.com/wfs/?service=WFS&request=GetFeature
&version=2.0.0&typeNames=example:layer&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
```

The layer is served as GML and contains about 400,000 features. The server limits a response to 100,000 features. [CQL is not supported.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153757/how-to-find-out-if-a-wfs-instance-supports-filtering-via-cql) The GML file contains such a node with each feature:

```xml
<gml:Point gml:id="P416" ... >
```

As far as I understand this `id` cannot be used to apply [paging via a `&FILTER` parameter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86755/how-to-use-paging-in-a-wfs-query).
How can I download the whole data set with *curl* - maybe with multiple downloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often even if filters or pagination are not supported, you can use the BBOX parameter to query features limited to a specific region. Via trial and error this can give you all the data. Just slice the area of interest into BBOXes that return less features than what the WFS is limited to.

For example `&BBOX=395000,5815000,400000,5820000` for a part of Berlin in EPSG:25833.

Comment: Good point. I already considered this. From *DescribeFeatureType* I found out that there is a `spatial_geometry` attribute which might be used for the `BBOX` fitler query. Still I have trouble constructing the correct `FILTER` parameter for the given WFS version as an (probably urlencoded string) for the HTTP GET request.

Comment: It's really just the URL parameter above: `service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typeNames=fis:re_strassenbaeume&BBOX=395000,5815000,400000,5820000` Looks safe with 10km tiles here but maybe just use 5km straightaway.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I found several more complicated ways to append a bounding box filter such as with `...<gml:coord><gml:X>...` or `...<gml:lowerCorner>...` and could not find out which is the proper to be used with WFS 2.0.0. Somehow I missed the simple way.

Answer (score 1):

The key section of the [WFS spec](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) is `7.7.4.4 Response paging` which gives an example:

```xml
<GetFeature service="WFS" version="2.0.0" count="100"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
  xmlns:cw="http://www.someserver.com/cw"
  xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/ogc/1.1"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
  <Query typeNames="cw:MyFeatureType"/>
</GetFeature>
```

So for you case you should change the count argument to 100000 (or possibly 99999 - depending on how strict the limit is). The response you get will include a **next** attribute which is the url of the next request, keep requesting the next urls until you get a response that doesn't have next set, that is the last one.

Comment: It seems paging is not supported: the *GetCapabilities* does **not** advertise `ImplementsResultPaging`. Nonetheless, I executed the request like this: `curl -vX GET http://example.com/wfs/?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typeNames=example:layer&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326&count=100000`. The response does **not** contain a `next` attribute.

Comment: can you name the service so I can have a play with it

Comment: [Here you are](http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_strassenbaeume/?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities). I used `EPSG:4326` in my question for simplification.

Comment: Make multiple requests with different BBOXes.